# ST_Intersect is giving wrong polygon back

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, shp2pgsql

I imported the french [IRIS dataset](https://geoservices.ign.fr/documentation/diffusion/telechargement-donnees-libres.html#contoursiris)  by shp2pgsql.

Added LAMB93 to the PostGIS spatial_ref_sys.

```
shp2pgsql -W latin1 -I -s 97527:4326 CONTOURS-IRIS.shp iris20 | psql -d iris20 -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1
```

So far so good, when I am trying to get the polygon for the point
45.827515,4.972910  (4326)
by

```
SELECT insee_com, code_iris FROM iris20 WHERE ST_Intersects(geom,ST_SetSRID(st_makepoint(4.972910, 45.827515), 4326));
```

My only result is: 013760000

But you can see on this homepage, the coordinate is on the border of the shape:
https://www.geoportail.gouv.fr/donnees/iris

Any help?

Comment: What is the `97527` EPSG ? The coordinates are in *France métropolitaine* and the coordinates system is Lambert-93, **epsg: 2154**, for me, your `shp2pgsql` command is wrong, even if it loads the entire table. After, I suggest you to make a little buffer around your `st_makepoint` with the `ST_BUFFER` PostGIS function.

Comment: I've added 7527 (97527) via https://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/ignflamb93/ , i tried 2154, same result for me. with ST_BUFFER, the resultset is in range, but why can't I use intersect? I assume the referencesystem is sliglty off?

Comment: Your coordinates are 2,24 m at East from the limit in the IRIS `013760000`, all is correct. I suggest you to make a buffer : `ST_SetSRID(ST_BUFFER(st_makepoint(4.972910, 45.827515), 0.00005), 4326)`. It's very hard to have a point perfectly on a polygon node, consider that a point is in one polygon (if polygons don't overlap). If you zoom on geoportail with the coordinates, you'll see the point not exactly on the limit.

Answer (score 2):

Are you shure that this point lies on that border? Intersecting points with lines is like spliting hair with an axe. It is possible, but it is very hart... You have to deal with 64 bit floating point precision coordinates and if there is marginal difference between them, there is no intersection. You should try to search polygons within small distance around that point. Something like this:

```
SELECT insee_com, code_iris FROM iris20 WHERE st_dwithin(geom,ST_SetSRID(st_makepoint(4.972910, 45.827515), 4326), 0.0001);
```

But, with 4326, that distance is specified as decimal degres, which is not optimal, becasu same value can express diferent real world distances based on position. So you should definitevely use planar coordinates system for that type of analysis.